# Please help to optimize MySql UPDATE with two tables and M:N row mapping

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm post-processing traces for two different kinds of events, where the data is stored in table A and B.  Both tables have an producer ID and a time index value.  While the same producer can trigger a record in both tables, the time when the different events occur are independent, and much more frequent for table B.

I want to update table A such that, for every row in table A, a column value from table B is taken for the most recent row in table B for the same producer.

Example mappings between two tables:

[image]

Here is a simplified example with just one producer in both tables.  The goal is not to get the oldest entry in table B, but rather the most recent entry in table B relative to a row in table A.  I'm showing B.tIdx < A.tIdx in this example, but <= is just as good for my purposes; just a detail.

```
Table A                               Table B                  
+----+------+----------------------+  +------+------+-------+
| ID | tIdx | NEW value SET FROM B |  | ID   | tIdx | value |
+----+------+----------------------+  +------+------+-------+
|  1 |    2 |                12.5  |  |    1 |    1 |  12.5 |
|  1 |    4 |                 4.3  |  |    1 |    2 |   9.0 |
+----+------+----------------------+  |    1 |    3 |   4.3 |
                                      |    1 |    4 |   7.8 |
                                      |    1 |    5 |   6.2 |
                                      +------+------+-------+
```

The actual tables have thousands of different IDs, millions of rows, and nearly as many distinct time index values as rows.  I'm having trouble to come up with an UPDATE that doesn't take days to complete.

The following UPDATE works, but executes far too slowly; it starts off at a rate of 100s of updates/s, but soon slows to roughly 5 updates/s.

```
UPDATE A AS x SET value = 
  (SELECT value 
   FROM B AS y 
   WHERE x.ID = y.ID AND x.tIdx > y.tIdx 
   ORDER BY y.tIdx DESC 
   LIMIT 1);
```

I've tried creating indexes for ID and tIdx separately, but also multi-column indexes with both orders (ID,tIdx) and (tIdx,ID).  But even when the multi-column indexes exist, EXPLAIN shows that it only ever indexes on ID or tIdx, but not both together.

I was wondering if the solution is to create nested SELECTs, to first get a temporary table with a particular ID, and then find the 1 row in table B that will meet the time constraint for each tIdx for that particular ID.  The following SELECT, with hardcoded ID and tIdx, works and is very fast, completing in 0.00 sec.

```
SELECT value, ID, tIdx
FROM (
    SELECT value, ID, tIdx
    FROM B
    WHERE ID = 5216
    ) y
 WHERE tIdx < 1253707 
 ORDER BY tIdx DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I'd like to incorporate this into an UPDATE somehow, but replace the hardcoded ID and tIdx with the ID,tIdx pair for each row in A.

Or try any other suggestion for a more efficient UPDATE statement.

This is my first post to stackoverflow.  Sincere apologizes in advance if I have violated any etiquette.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 5.7.20-log
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: See if these help:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: @RickJames -> That looks very promising.  I haven't had a chance to incorporate that knowledge yet, but I am very eager to give that try.  I'll post back when I get it done.  Aside: I cannot read your name without thinking of the Dave Chappelle skit.  Sorry!

Comment: @bnoronb - Hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Update with Inner Join should do it, but it's going to get nasty to do this.

```
Update a INNER JOIN
       (Select b.ID, maxb.atIdx, b.value
        From b INNER JOIN (Select a.ID, a.tIdx as atIdx, max(b.tIdx) as bigb
                           From b INNER JOIN a
                                  ON b.ID=a.ID
                           Where b.tIdx<=a.tIdx
                           Group By a.ID,a.tIdx) maxb
               ON b.ID=maxb.ID and b.tIdx=maxb.bigb
        ) bestb ON a.ID=bestb.ID and a.tIdx=bestb.atIdx
Set a.value=bestb.value
```

To explain this it's best to start with the innermost SQL and work your way to the outermost UPDATE.  To start, we need to join every record in table A to every record in table B for each ID.  We can filter out the B records that are too recent and summarize that result for each table A record.  That leaves us with the tIdx of the B table whose value goes into A for every record key in A.  So then we join that to the B table to select the values to update, preserving the A-table's keys.  That result is joined back to A to perform the update.

You'll have to see whether this is fast enough for you - I'm worried that this accesses the B table twice and the inner query creates **A LOT** of join combinations.  I would pull out that inner query and see how long it runs by itself.  On the positive side, they are all very simple, straightforward queries and they are connected by Inner Joins so there is some opportunity for efficiency in the query optimizer.  I think indexes on a(ID,TIdx) [*fast lookup to get the Update row*] and b(ID) would be useful here.

Comment: I updated this SQL based on BnoronB's clarifications to the problem statement.  It now updates EVERY value in table A based on the latest value in table B earlier than table A.  I'd appreciate some feedback as to whether this is an improvement over your slow SQL.  I THINK it is because it does not run a SQL for every value in the A table.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your suggestion.  I think functionally this new version does the job.  Unfortunately my performance testing did not yield good results.  When I tried the UPDATE,  show ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G reported 0.00 updates/s.  It was working, just really slowly.  I converted your update command  to a SELECT...LIMIT 1, on the outside, but the three INNER JOIN all identical.  It took 1 row in set (57 min 28.54 sec).

Comment: drat.  Let me see  if I can think of something else.  In theory you would not need to examine all pairs of A with B for an ID if you reverse sorted both A and B by tIdx and started running down the two lists side-by-side.  That would turn it from O(n*m) to O(n+m).  I know how to do that procedurally but not with SQL.

Comment: On reflection, it seems to me that the Select part of this query works real hard to produce a result, but then the Update is straightforward.  I’m thinking that if Limit 1 took ~1hour to reach a result then Limit 2 will take the same 1 hour.  The question is whether one hour and a little more (to complete thousands of updates) is better than what you already had.  Anyway, if you can spare the time check the timing on Limit 2 - I think you'll get the same 57 minutes.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but other testing I've done has shown that the completion time for a SELECT scales with LIMIT.  I was performance testing a complicated SELECT.  I  was using LIMIT X so my console didn't fill with text.  My assumption was that the SELECT would complete first, entirely, and after the output would get limited.  I didn't think it would impact my performance test.  I finally got a reasonable time for my SELECT (with the LIMIT) of a just a few seconds.  But I was surprised to discover that when I removed LIMIT, it still took hours to complete.  Roughly (totalrows)/X x time.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is `lead()` to see if that helps the performance:

```
UPDATE A JOIN
       (SELECT b.*,
              LEAD(tIDx) OVER (PARTITION BY id order by tIDx) as next_tIDx
        FROM b
       ) b
       ON a.id = b.id AND
          a.tIDx >= b.tIDx AND
          (b.next_tIDx IS NULL or a.tIDx < b.next_tIDx)
    SET a.value = b.value;
```

And for this you want an index on `b(id, tidx)`.

Comment: unfortunately they are on 5.7

Comment: I should have mentioned in my original question that currently the database is 5.7.  Is it possible there is a 5.7 equivalent to the suggestion?  In the long run in might be possible to upgrade to 8.0, and if that happens I will try the above suggestion.  But in the short term I'm constrained to 5.7.

Comment: I still plan to give this answer a try as well, once I get a MySql 8.0 installed and populated with data.  I will reply back when it is done, but it might be days or even weeks.  I suspect this is going to be the best solution.

Comment: @bnoronb . . . Although possible to do in older versions of MySQL, it is tricky and likely to have poor performance.